# Why does the Camel CXF endpoint use a part of the path string provided with the SOAP request to build the URL for the http component?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route which offers a SOAP service and passes the request to a simple HTTP service.

I have the following setup in my `blueprint.xml`file:

```
 <camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="pingService" 
             address="http://localhost:8989/soap"
             serviceClass="ch.example.PingService" />

 <route id="ping">
      <from uri="cxf:bean:pingService" />
      <to uri="http4://destination.lo/ping?bridgeEndpoint=true"/>
 </route>
```

The PingService looks like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "PingService")
public interface PingService {        
    String ping(String s);
}
```

When I send a SOAP request to http://localhost:8989/soap all is working fine and http://destination.lo/ping is properly called.

However, when I append a string to the SOAP endpoint URI (e.g. http://localhost:8989/soap/foo), the string */foo* is appended to the URI of the destination endpoint like so: http://destination.lo/ping/foo

I have tried disabling this behavior by manually defining the URI like so:

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri">
    <constant>http://destination.lo/ping</constant>
</setHeader>
```

But this does not help.

How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The http4 documentation on `bridgeEndpoint`:

> If true, HttpProducer will ignore the Exchange.HTTP_URI header, and
>   use the endpoint's URI for request.

From the [Camel proxy](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html) overview page I take it that you should use the [UrlRewrite component](http://camel.apache.org/urlrewrite.html) if you need anything but a 1:1 URL mapping.